# With the LibPurple chat_add_users callback, how do I get a display image from a PurpleConvChatBuddy?

Tags: libpurple

In the LibPurple chat_add_users callback, you get a list of PurpleConvChatBuddy object's describing all the chat users.  What is the best way to get the buddy icon / or user info photo for each of the users?

I can't find any nice way to connect a PurpleConvChatBuddy object to a buddy icon, the best I can come up with is to request the userinfo and then figure out the 'photo' entry in the returned values.  This does not seem to be the best way to handle it in a generic way.

Comment: It's been a while since I hacked on LibPurple -- I don't know the answer, but I often found ideas by looking in one of the clients to see how they handled it.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, I've mainly been looking through how the Pidgin client works.  But it doesn't have this functionality in it and I can't see a way in the LibPurple API.  I'll try looking wider at other clients to see what they do.  Thanks for the comment.